# Display a list of the values of a selection of checked boxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a UL of checkboxes in a jquery Tree. I want to display a comma separated list of the ones that are checked off below the entire list (as a way for the user to visually see all items they have checked off). How would I do this with jquery? I am note sure where to begin. Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
          <li><span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Item 1" id="Item1"/>
            <label>Item 1</label>
            </span>
            <ul>
              <li><span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Item 1.0" id="Item1-0"/>
                <label>Item 1.0</label>
                </span>
                <ul>
                  <li><span>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Item 1.0.0" id="Item1-0-0"/>
                    <label>Item 1.0</label>
                    </span></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Item 1.1" id="Item1-1"/>
                <label>Item 1.1</label>
                </span></li>
              <li><span>
                <input type="checkbox" value="Item 1.2" id="Item1-2"/>
                <label>Item 1.2</label>
                </span>
                <ul>
                  <li><span>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Item 1.2.0" id="Item1-2-0"/>
                    <label>Item 1.2.0</label>
                    </span> </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
<ul>
<div class="currently-selected">
    Currently Selected:
    <span>Item 1</span>,<span>Item 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try The following code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/X7FNQ/2/)**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
    $(".currently-selected").html("Currently Selected:");
    var arrTemp = [];

    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(ind, val){
         arrTemp.push("<span>" + $(val).val() + "</span>");
    });

    $(".currently-selected").append(arrTemp.join());
});
```

Comment: That doesn't quite do it. I only want the items checked to display next to Currently selected. So if 1.0 and 1.2 are the only items checked, it should say "Currently Selected: 1.0, 1.2" and disregard the parents.